# How to bind an event to the checkbox in the objectlistview in wxpython

Tags: checkbox, wxpython, objectlistview-python

I'm using objectlistview in wxpython and I am very happy with it until now. I cannot find a way to add an event to the checkbox in my objectlistview. At the moment I have a workaround, the user have to click on a button and then something happens with the checked row. But I would like to make it happen when the user checks the checkbox. It have to toggle a graph in my plot.

A second question I have is how I can uncheck the checkboxes after the user clicked the button (this is for if there isn't a way to solve my first question).

My code (I just copied the necessary lines, because my program is very big)

```
self.tempmeasurements = ObjectListView(self, wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.LC_REPORT | wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
self.tempmeasurements.SetColumns(microanalysis_options.TempMeasColumndefs)
self.tempmeasurements.CreateCheckStateColumn(0)
self.addbutton = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Add to plot")
self.rembutton = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY,'Remove from plot')

self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_toggle_plotlist, self.addbutton)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_remove_from_plot,self.rembutton)

def on_toggle_plotlist(self, event):
    objectsAddPlotList = self.tempmeasurements.GetCheckedObjects()
    pub.sendMessage('MA_ADD_TO_PLOT', Container(origin=self, data=objectsAddPlotList)) #to microanalyse controller
    self.tempmeasurements.SetCheckState(objectsAddPlotList,False)

def on_remove_from_plot(self,event):
    objectsAddPlotList = self.tempmeasurements.GetCheckedObjects()
    pub.sendMessage('MA_REM_FROM_PLOT', Container(origin=self, data=objectsAddPlotList))  # to microanalyse controller
```

The self.tempmeasurements.SetCheckState(objectsAddPlotList,False) line I tried to use to uncheck the checkboxes after the user clicked the button.

this is how the list looks like:

[image: list with checkboxes]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing is to import `OLVEvent` and then bind your `ObjectListView` instance to `OLVEvent.EVT_ITEM_CHECKED`.

I went ahead and created a simple example:

```
import wx

from ObjectListView import ObjectListView, ColumnDefn, OLVEvent


class Results(object):
    """"""

    def __init__(self, tin, zip_code, plus4, name, address):
        """Constructor"""
        self.tin = tin
        self.zip_code = zip_code
        self.plus4 = plus4
        self.name = name
        self.address = address


class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.test_data = [Results("123456789", "50158", "0065", "Patti Jones",
                                  "111 Centennial Drive"),
                          Results("978561236", "90056", "7890", "Brian Wilson",
                                  "555 Torque Maui"),
                          Results("456897852", "70014", "6545", "Mike Love", 
                                  "304 Cali Bvld")
                          ]
        self.results_olv = ObjectListView(self, 
                                         style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.results_olv.Bind(OLVEvent.EVT_ITEM_CHECKED, self.on_item_checked)

        self.set_results()

        mainSizer.Add(self.results_olv, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)

    def on_item_checked(self, event):
        obj = self.results_olv.GetSelectedObject()
        checked = 'Checked' if self.results_olv.IsChecked(obj) else 'Unchecked'
        print('{} row is {}'.format(obj.name, checked))

    def set_results(self):
        """"""
        self.results_olv.SetColumns([
            ColumnDefn("TIN", "left", 100, "tin"),
            ColumnDefn("Zip", "left", 75, "zip_code"),
            ColumnDefn("+4", "left", 50, "plus4"),
            ColumnDefn("Name", "left", 150, "name"),
            ColumnDefn("Address", "left", 200, "address")
        ])
        self.results_olv.CreateCheckStateColumn()
        self.results_olv.SetObjects(self.test_data)


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        title = "OLV Checkbox Tutorial"
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title=title, 
                          size=(600, 400))
        panel = MyPanel(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Hey Mike, thank you for your answer, I will try it out!

Comment: Hey Mike, Thank you very much! This is exactly what I need! TX!